# Cannot connect LogStash to AWS ElasticSearch "Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error"

Tags: amazon-ec2, logstash, amazon-iam, ubuntu-18.04, aws-elasticsearch

I am building a setup which consists of AWS ElasticSearch (includes both ElasticSearch and Kibana), LogStash and FileBeat. I have been following [this tutorial](https://sysadmins.co.za/setup-a-logstash-server-for-amazon-elasticsearch-service-and-auth-with-iam/) which explains how to Setup a Logstash Server for Amazon Elasticsearch Service and Auth with IAM.

I am using an Ubuntu 18.04 EC2 m4.large instance to host both LogStash and FileBeat. I have provisioned all of my assets inside a VPC. So far, I have provisioned an AWS ES domain, an Ubuntu 18.04 EC2 and then installed LogStash inside that. Right now, I am ignoring FileBeat and I just want to connect my LogStash service to the AWS ES domain.

As per the tutorial, I have

1. Created an IAM Access Policy
2. Created Role logstash-system-es with "ec2.amazonaws.com" as trusted entity
3. Authorized the Role in my AWS ES domain dashboard
4. Installed LogStash and configured as specified
   (Here I entered the Access Key I am using and its ID into the output section. However, I am not sure how the Role and an Access Key relates to each other)
5. Started LogStash and tailed the logstash-plain.log file to see the output

When I check the output it appears LogStash cannot connect to the ES domain.The following line starts occurring infinitely. (I have replaced the AWS ES domain name with **AWSESDOMAIN**).

> Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an
> error.
> {:url=>"https://vpc-**AWSESDOMAIN**.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:443/",
> :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::AmazonElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError,
> :error=>"Got response code '403' contacting Elasticsearch at URL
> 'https://vpc-**AWSESDOMAIN**.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:443/'"}

FYI I have configured my AWS ES domain with Fine Grained Access Control when setting it up.

What seems to be the issue here? Is it regarding Fine Grained Access Control? Security Groups? IAM issue?

Comment: where is Logstash deployed? is it in the same vpc of the elasticsearch domain?

Comment: @glenacota Yes, in the same VPC.

Comment: Then, next, I'd check that Logstash has access to the domain through the VPC security groups

Comment: @glenacota You mean, Inbound Rules? I checked. In fact, I even allowed access for All the Traffic from anywhere. (I know it's not the Best Practice, I just wanted to make sure).

Comment: please check that the Logstash host and the Elasticsearch domain has the same security group

Comment: @glenacota They are in two different groups. I want the LogStash host and the ES domain to have different Inbound Rules.